# removing .php in ahref and still linking from old page

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have an older PHP website where I've removed the `.php` extension from PHP files getting accessed and showing in the browser.

After I have added the relevant `.htaccess` parts and changed anchor's `href` from `href="index.php"` to `href="index"`, is there any way to make the old one still work for SEO from pages that are for example indexed in Google?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to make the old one still work for SEO from pages that is for example indexed in google ?

Yes, this is essential if you are *changing* an existing URL format.

However, you do need to be careful of redirect loops, since you need to avoid redirecting the rewritten request that appends the `.php` extension.

You can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing rewrite (after the `RewriteEngine` directive):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The *condition* that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable avoids the redirect loop, since this is *empty* on the initial request from the client and set to "200" (as in 200 OK status) after the later rewrite.

You should test this first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.